# toolbar icon's not totaly white

Tags: android

Lately I have had this problem, which is quite annoying where an icon is not "totally" white, it is in a half gray tone, there are two icons below for a better understanding, I would like the "search" icon to be the same color That of "completed."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deeply appreciate all the help. I was able to solve this using an SVG asset vector.

Comment: That means my answer was right ? If yes then mark the answer as the correct one, or at least add a comment to the answer. That will help in the future to the people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can change colors in one go.

```
<style name="YourAppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Set color in a theme and Apply that theme to your App. If you already have theme then just add `android:textColorSecondary` in that theme.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the icon you are using has some transparency.
If your are using icons from the android SDK icon library then many of them have semi-transparency and the result is some mix between white and the background color.

If you want a fully white icon then you need a not transparent icon.

Comment: The problem was solved through a white svg icon.
Thank you for your response and attention.